# Interactive Tree Visualization using wxPython

Tags: tree, wxpython

I need to display a tree like this:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Binary_tree.svg

with the following things to consider:

1) The model is not necessarily a binary tree, it could be any tree data structure.

2) The tree nodes should be clickable.

3) The node colors/shapes may be changed programmatically.

4) It should be possible to zoom in and out and also scroll around since the tree may get very big.

5) My code is is wxPython, so I would like to find something that is compatible with wx.

6) It should run on Linux and Mac.

I am trying to find a library to visualize and interact with such tree views. The closest thing I have found is http://ete.cgenomics.org/ but it uses PyQt4. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you'll have to do this yourself somehow as I'm not aware of anything that does it out of the box in wxPython. The FloatCanvas can do some of what you require. You might also look at matplotlib, which does all kinds of graphs and can be integrated with wxPython pretty easily.